# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager hile attempting to activate 'Controllers.AccountsController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have the following code in the AccountsController :

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Products.Helpers;
using Products.Models;
using Products.ViewModels;

namespace Products.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ContextUsers _appDbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AccountsController(ContextUsers context,UserManager<AppUser> userManager,IMapper mapper)
    {
        _appDbContext = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

        await _appDbContext.Customers.AddAsync(new Customer { IdentityId = userIdentity.Id, Location = model.Location });
        await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
    }
}
```

}

And I have the following code in the AppUser class:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
  // Extended Properties
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public long? FacebookId { get; set; }
  public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And the following Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string IdentityId { get; set; }
 public AppUser Identity { get; set; }  // navigation property
 public string Location { get; set; }
 public string Locale { get; set; }
 public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

When i make a post request in postman i get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Products.Models.AppUser]' while attempting to activate 'Products.Controllers.AccountsController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
```

I am trying to create a user but when I make the post request doesn't even enter the controller so I can't debug

ConfigureServices method from startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

                .AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin();
            }));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LaprDB")));
            services.AddDbContext<ContextUsers>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));


            services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();

             services.AddAutoMapper();


        }
```

Comment: What does the `ConfigureServices` method in your `Startup.cs` class look like?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a line to add the Identity object to the DI container. You need to call the [`AddDefaultIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionuiextensions.adddefaultidentity?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions_AddDefaultIdentity__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_IdentityOptions__) method. Add this line to the `ConfigureServices` method in your `Startup` class:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ContextUsers>();
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for more information on setting up Identity.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but now i'm getting this error:

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.`

Comment: That's a completely different problem. AutoMapper has nothing to do with Identity so it's something you have set up here. Honestly, it sounds like you've been copying and pasting code without understanding how any of it works. I suggest your best option is to go and try to figure out what it's all doing.

Comment: Note that this will also add the Default UI, which might not be wanted in this case.